# Does an opportunity attack that stuns prevent the movement?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, immediate-actions

If I make an opportunity attack with some combination of riders that will cause a hit to stun (or if the victim has already taken some action, daze) can the target of my attack continue their movement?

> **Opportunity Attack**
>
> Moving Provokes: If an enemy leaves a square adjacent to you, you can make an opportunity attack against that enemy. However, you can’t make one if the enemy shifts or teleports or is forced to move away by a pull, a push, or a slide.
>
> ...
>
> Interrupts Target’s Action: An opportunity action takes place before the target finishes its action. After the opportunity attack, the creature resumes its action. If the target is reduced to 0 hit points or fewer by the opportunity attack, it can’t finish its action because it’s dead or dying.
>
> **Immediate Actions**
>
> Interrupt: An immediate interrupt lets you jump in when a certain trigger condition arises, acting before the trigger resolves. If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost.

So, which takes precedence? The daze or stun invalidating the movement? Or the comment that after the opportunity action the creature resumes its action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> After the opportunity attack, the creature **resumes** its action. [Emphasis mine.]

It doesn't say that the target gets to **complete** its action, only that it gets to **resume** it. However, now that the target is stunned (or, as you point out, dazed, if it has already taken another action), the action it was performing is now invalid, so upon resuming the action said action now simply fails. I think this is what they were trying to express with that last bit about "If the target is reduced to 0 hit points...", but they could have been more general to make it more clear.

The same would happen if an AoO were to render a target immobilized, for example -- it now *can't* move, so its movement action now fails.

Comment: O_O I somewhat could not interpret what you just said or I'm just more tired than I thought.  You're basically saying if the attack stuns them on the movement provoke, then they can't finish the movement cause of no actions; Dazing would be similar in that it fails to continue IF the target did one other action prior; and the immobilized example, the movement action fails basically because you just expended a movement that is now impossible (Assuming you had a standard and a minor left if you weren't dazed or stunned), correct?

Comment: @zapoqx Yep, that's how it works. Action prvokes OA -> OA goes off -> creature resumes its turn *with any conditions applied by the OA*. Follow normal rules for stunning, dazing, etc at that point. Also note that the creature can save against those effects (if applicable) at the end of it's current turn, so you may not get as much out of the stun as normal.

Comment: Ok.  Just wanted to clarify if anyone was in the same boat as I was reading that.  I knew it works like that anyway, just the way it was written and how I saw it last night made it seem like it conflicted with what I knew how OA works with such conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Compare for instance the description of the "Slowed" condition:

> Slowed
>
> Your speed becomes 2. This speed applies to all your movement modes, but it does not apply to teleportation or to a pull, a push, or a slide. You can’t increase your speed above 2, and your speed doesn’t increase if it was lower than 2. **If you’re slowed while moving, stop moving if you have already moved 2 or more squares.**

It's quite clear that if something happens to you while you're moving (an OA, a trap or environmental hazard, an immediate interrupt) it can end the move in the middle of things.