# If I'm dazed do I forget to attack after charging?

Tags: dnd-4e, charge, daze

I know if my first action of a turn is *Charge*, then *Daze* will not stop the charge.

What happens if *Daze* is the second action of the turn? Can *Daze* stop the *Charge* then ?

Sequence of events:

1. I do a move action
2. I declare *Charge* and do the move portion of the charge
3. I trigger an opportunity attack and get hit and become dazed

Can I now do the attack from the *Charge*, or is it lost?

Answer (score 14):

Opportunity attacks interrupt the current action (meaning they happen as soon as they are triggered either before an attack or before leaving the adjacent square).

One of the properties of interrupts is that actions that are no longer valid are lost.

> If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost. ([DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=120))

Thus the movement would be stopped on the daze (as you lack the standard action the charge you are in the midst of requires... similar to [Does an opportunity attack that stuns prevent the movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8685/1084)) and the attack would not happen as it would be the completion of the charge action.

If you are still in a valid position to charge, an action point may be spent to charge, but I do not think that an action point could be spent to resume the charge rather than start a new one.

Comment: I don't see how the dazed condition would end the action you're in the middle of. It will clearly prevent you from spending additional actions, but not finishing an action you've already spent.

Comment: @EugeneKatz if you get dazed in the middle of a move after you've already taken an action you're move is over. Same goes for charging here. Because you've already acted any further actions are invalid, even completing the current one.

Comment: @EugeneKatz http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8685/1084 reaches the same conclusion I do

Comment: @waxeagle The question you reference mainly focuses on the stunned condition and only mentions dazed as an aside. Stunned is more restrictive; it doesn't let you take any action, not even free ones, and a flying creature would drop unless it can hover. Dazed just alters the action economy for the current round. You can't take any additional non-free actions if you've reached the limit, but there is no reason why you can't finish the one that's already started.

Comment: @EugeneKatz my question about OA and stunned references dazed in exactly the same way that this question does - in the middle of an action the right to take that action is removed... does the action continue? In both that question and this answer, the suggestion is "No, the action does not continue."

Comment: @simonwithers,I agree with the answer when it comes to stunned, but believe that dazed should not be treated the same.

Comment: @EugeneKatz this is effectively the same thing though, with stunned you are out of actions, in this case with dazed you are also out of actions.

Comment: @waxeagle you don't have any more actions to spend, that's true. However, you've already spent the action to begin the charge, so why should you not be able to finish it? Think of resuming the charge being similar to a free actions. You can take free actions when dazed, but not when stunned. I'm not saying it's actually a free action, but ability to take a free action is one of the differences between stunned and dazed. And I think being able to resume a charge is another.

Comment: @EugeneKatz I am understanding your contention to be that "resuming an action that has been started" is (or is at least very similar to) a free action, and so resuming an action is possible when dazed, but not when stunned?

Comment: @SimonWithers precisely. There is nothing about dazed which says resuming the action you've started is illegal. And my point is that using stunned as a guideline is not valid.

Comment: @EugeneKatz fair enough :) ... not sure that I agree, but you reasoning is much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've already spent the action to initiate the charge, getting dazed in the middle of it should not invalidate your action. Dazed condition would prevent you from taking additional non-free actions (and technically that's the case at the end of a charge anyway), but since you've already cashed in your standard action to initiate the charge, you should be able to finish it.

Unlike examples where an interrupt invalidates the action which triggered it, there is nothing about being dazed that would make completing the charge (action you've already started) illegal. And you clearly must have started the charge action, even if you have not started the movement portion of it yet, because that is what the opportunity attack is triggered by.